# Adobe Acrobat Reader can't open PKCS#12 file with correct password

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography

I'm using the cryptography library to generate certificates, but I'm having trouble with it, so let me explain the steps I take. The problem is that the final PKCS#12 file can't be imported to Adobe Acrobat Reader even though I enter the correct password. These are the steps:

1. Create a private key with a given password

```py
key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048)
key_bytes = key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(
        password.encode('utf-8')
    )
)
# save the private key to a file
```

2. Create a Certificate Signing Request with some properties:

```py
csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, 'NL'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, 'AAA'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, 'BBB'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, 'CCC'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.EMAIL_ADDRESS, 'DDD')
])).sign(key, hashes.SHA256())
csr_bytes = csr.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM)
# save the crt to a file
```

3. Use XCA to create a certificate. I import the request, then select "Digital Signature" as Key Usage, and "Object Signing" under Netscape. Right after that, the csr is signed, and I export the generated certificate to a file.
4. Load the private key from the file with

```py
key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    data,  # file data
    password.encode('utf-8')
)
```

5. Load the certificate from the file with

```py
certificate = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(data)  # certificate data
```

6. Generate the PKCS#12 with

```py
user_certificate_bytes = pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates(
    name=None,
    key=key,
    cert=certificate,
    cas=None,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(
        password.encode('utf-8')
    )
)
```

and export it to a file.

7. Open the PKCS#12 file in Adobe Acrobat Reader via Edit > Preferences > Signatures > Identity & trusted certificates. However, when I now want to import my certificate and filling in the correct password, it says it can't import the certificate, even though the password is 100% correct.

To be clear, when I generate the PKCS#12 file with OpenSSL with  `openssl pkcs12 -export -out XXX.pfx -inkey <private key file> -in <certificate file>`, the import goes without any problem.

I'm not sure where my mistake is, hope you can help!

EDIT: Also, when dumping the contents of this generated certificate file and a correct one I had laying around, it seems cryptography is using `pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC` as the serialization (?) algorithm, while the correct one had `pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC`. Could that be a difference?

Comment: Could be, although RC2 is usually only used for the certificate, which would be *fine*. The API says that: "Maximum compatibility can be achieved by using SHA1 for MAC algorithm and PBESv1SHA1And3KeyTripleDESCBC for encryption algorithm as seen in the example below. ", and also that this is quite insecure, but it could help.

Comment: By the way, Java uses RC2 for the cert, and 3DES for the key. This doesn't make much sense (which seems to be normality  for PKCS#12) but that's probably the most compatible option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using

```py
encryption = (
    PrivateFormat.PKCS12.encryption_builder().
    kdf_rounds(50000).
    key_cert_algorithm(pkcs12.PBES.PBESv1SHA1And3KeyTripleDESCBC).
    hmac_hash(hashes.SHA1()).build(b"my password")
)
```

as suggested in the docs as the encryption algorithm when serializing the private key and certificate. I probably should update my PDF to allow better and newer encryption methods :)